# Opening a port from a docker container on AWS to the rest of the world

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, port

I'm trying to host a python HTTPS server on Amazon Web Services using Docker.
The application "*application.py*" works well when executed on my local computer on the arbitrary port 8012.

The problem is that the required port is not open when I try to run the same application remotely.
Here are the configuration files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2-onbuild
ADD . /mnt
EXPOSE 8012
WORKDIR /mnt
CMD [ "python", "./application.py" ]
```

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
     {
     "ContainerPort": "8012",
     "hostPort": "8012"
     }
   ]
}
```

Inspecting the running docker instance on AWS gives the following parameters:

```
"Config": {
"ExposedPorts": {
    "8012/tcp": {}
    }
 }
...
"NetworkSettings": {
"PortMapping": null,
     "Ports": {
         "8012/tcp": null
     }
}
```

Does someone know how to transform a "403 connection refused" to a "200 OK" by opening this port ?
Since the application is made to be automatically scaled , I can only use the configuration files and can't use the following:

```
  docker run -p 8012:8012...
```

Comment: Did you open 8012 in AWS under Security Groups?

Comment: Yes, the inbound TCP traffic is allowed on port 8012. All the outbound traffic is allowed.

Comment: This looks wrong to me: `"PortMapping": null,
     "Ports": {
         "8012/tcp": null
     }
}`

Comment: I agree but it is the output of the command `docker inspect <my container id>`. My question, if I understand a bit how it works, was how to configure my project to set the correct port mapping.